# Problem with creating java anonymous class with generics in scala

Tags: java, generics, scala

For example I have following Java inteface

```
public interface Test<T,M> {
       public M get(T t);
}
```

if I whant create ananymoys class in java with this interface

```
val t = new Test[Int,Boolean](){
     def get(t: Boolean) = 0
}
```

I have following error

> Scala.scala:15: error:
>   scal.test.example.Test does not take
>   type parameters val t = new Test[Int,Boolean](){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was old version of scala 2.6.1. It was installed by default from maven archity for scala projects. Now I upgraded version to 2.8.0 and problem was solved. For old version your need to scpecify the version of java.

Answer (score 4):

Enclosing your Scala code in an object for separate compilation and correcting the order of the type parameters:

```
object TestI {
    val t = new Test[Boolean,Int]() {
        def get(t: Boolean) = 0
    }
}
```

... I do not get any compilation errors.

Comment: I tried this and get the same error. I use maven for compilation with scala compile plugin with version 2.6.1 and scala 2.8

Comment: I suspect either your Java interface is not in the same package as your Scala class, you failed to import that interface, Maven isn't compiling the Java first, the Java-generated `.class` files aren't in the class-path during Scala compilation or some combination thereof.

Comment: This is not a problem becouse the following code works fine                   val t = new Test() {
        def get(t: Any) = null
    } That is you version of scala?

Comment: I should have noticed that your diagnostic was not about an undefined `Test`, but rather about a `Test` that was being used in a manner not consistent with its definition.